# Is the requirement of a field a functional or nonfunctional requirement?

Tags: requirements, functional-requirements

Is the requirement of a field a functional or nonfunctional requirement?

Maybe it is nonfunctional because it is a characteristic of the system.

I have to list functional and nonfunctional requirements in two tables. I did this:

Functional requirements:

1. Register product:
   The system must register a product. It will have fields name, photo, ....

Nonfunctional requirements:

1. When registering a product some fields are required, including the name field.

Traceability matrix:

```
    FR1 FR2
NR1 X
NR2     X
```

What am I doing right and wrong?

Comment: I don't know. It is more related to how the system should do than what it should do. It is more lated to validation than to functionality for me.

Answer (score 3):

Requiring specific fields to be mandatory is a [functional requirement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/379985/209774).  It describes **what** the system needs to do (e.g. verify that a value is entered in the field), and not **how** or **how well** the system shall do it.

The t[raceability matrix](https://project-management.com/requirements-traceability-matrix-rtm/) does not link FR to NFR.  But it links requirements (FR and NFR) to either the origin that lead to the requirement (narrative text,  interview, etc...) or design elements to the requirements.